# How to create MFC windows applicaion project Visual studio c++ 2010 expess (or any other alternative)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have to do  small project of creating rectangle and circle which will change it's color using MFC application wizard.

I tried installing VS 2010 express for it and i do not find any MFC application wizard in it.
 please see this for example http://prntscr.com/42ps8k .

How to create MFC poject in  VS 2010 c++ express ?

If not possible in express then what link should i follow (i mean what sequence of installations should i do to achieve my target) ?

Comment: Express editions don't include MFC (nor ATL). Only non-free editions do. Follow [this link](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/how-to-buy-vs)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so there is no free way to achieve this small task of drawing circle and square  in WIN API ?

Comment: Yes, without MFC. :-) Pure Win32.

Comment: @Xearinox sorry ..Pure Win32 means ?

Comment: Learn to Program for Windows in C++: [Module 1. Your First Windows Program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381409.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable could you please explain how to create this project ? to draw window to draw circle and rectangle? Is it still a mfc project ? or any other ?

Comment: This is a regular Win32 GUI application. Instructions on how to create a Win32 GUI application can be found at [Creating Win32-Based Applications (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik what about [VS community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx), its free ;)

Comment: @rustyx It didn't exist back in July 2014 when this question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Express editions do not include MFC.

Use [Visual Studio Community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx), it has MFC support.